# How to create your own type and use it to store data

Tags: vb.net, class, types, dictionary

I've recently ran into the problem that dictionary only allows 1 value per key. Reading around I have seen multiple answers suggesting creating a type through a classes. Now granted I don't know much about classes, I have always though that classes were just a collection of functions and subs. How come they can create data types and how do you use them to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic definition of a `Dictionary` is given by `Dictionary(Of type1, type2)`, where types can be anything, that is, primitive types (`String`, `Double`, etc.) or ones you create (via `Class`, for example). Also you can account for them as "individual variables" or inside collections (`Lists`, `Arrays`, etc.). Some examples:

```
 Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))

 Dim tempList = New List(Of String)
 tempList.Add("val11")
 tempList.Add("val12")
 tempList.Add("val13")

 dict.Add("1", tempList)

 Dim dict2 = New Dictionary(Of String, type2)
 Dim tempProp = New type2
 With tempProp
     .prop1 = "11"
     .prop2 = "12"
     .prop2 = "13"
 End With
 dict2.Add("1", tempProp)

 Dim dict3 = New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of type2))
 Dim tempPropList = New List(Of type2)
 Dim tempProp2 = New type2
 With tempProp2
     .prop1 = "11"
     .prop2 = "12"
     .prop2 = "13"
 End With
 tempPropList.Add(tempProp2)

 dict3.Add("1", tempPropList)
```

Where `type2` is defined by the following Class:

```
Public Class type2
    Public prop1 As String
    Public prop2 As String
    Public prop3 As String
End Class
```

NOTE: you can change the types in the examples above as much as you wish; also put anything (List, custom types, etc.) in both `Values` and `Keys`.

NOTE2: the primitive types in VB.NET (for example: `Double`) are basically a bunch of variables (declared globally inside the given framework) and functions: `Double.IsInfinity` (function), `Double.MaxValue` (variable), etc.; thus a type can be understood as an in-built Class, that is, a general name for a group of functions and variables, which can be used to define another variable in a different Class. I think that the proposed example is pretty descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

Classes aren't just about functions and subs, they also contains variable and properties. Which can be used to store a bunch of values.

Lets say you want to store the first name and last name of a person in the dictionnary by person number.

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Number As String
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
End Class

Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of String, Person)
Dim p = New Person

p.Number = "A123"
p.FirstName = "John"
p.LastName = "Doe"

dict.Add(p.Number, p)
```

And then to fetch the person back

```
p = dict("A123")

Console.WriteLine(p.FirstName)
Console.WriteLine(p.LastName)
```

Comment: You should put the class in a different block of code to highlight its difference with respect to the code below (a non-too-expert reader might think that can put everything inside the same function). Your dictionary is wrongly defined (or populated): you are defining it as a (string, list of person) but populating it with a (string, person) (your code does not even compile). You are making things even more confusing for the OP (even by ignoring the error): you are mixing up classes with lists without any justification; point which I thought that was pretty clear in my answer already.

Comment: Sorry for what I said yesterday. I don't think that you had the best behaviour but @UrielKatz has helped me realise that I shouldn't have treated you like this.

Answer (score 0):

After combining knowledge from this and other sources, here is my final solution:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dictionary = New Dictionary(Of String, Pair)
        Dim p As New Pair("A", "B")

        MsgBox(p.First)
        MsgBox(p.Second)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Pair
    Private ReadOnly value1 As String
    Private ReadOnly value2 As String

    Sub New(first As String, second As String)
        value1 = first
        value2 = second
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property First() As String
        Get
            Return value1
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Second() As String
        Get
            Return value2
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Just as a comment to make sure that you got everything right: you can include in a class anything you want (and you will be accessing all this information from the variables you declare from it). You can include properties (what you are doing) or variables/fields (what I did) or functions. Instead single variables/properties, you can declare arrays/list and instantiate them automatically from a sub on the constructor. Your code is basically doing the same than the the_lotus one, although his relies on a summarised way to declare properties.

Comment: As far as the_lotus code says basically the same (properties and variables are practically speaking the same) than part of my answer (written 6 hours before) and your answer says the same than the_lotus one (with more lines of code), I guess that you will understand why I don't upvote you. I hope that your ideas have got a bit clearer after these comments.

Comment: @varocarbas I have given you credit for you answer, I marked the wrong one previously by accident. Since you have given more information (6 hours before) and took the time to respond to my answer I feel it is fair to give you credit. Also please refrain from posting offensive comments.

Comment: Thanks. In any case, bear in mind that you can select/upvote any answer you wish and I cannot say anything unless being clearly wrong (but this wasn't the case). My intention was just letting the ideas clear for you and for any future reader. Personally, I didn't like at all the attitude shown by the_lotus and this might be slightly reflected in the tone of my comments; but, other than that, I don't get what you mean with offensive. I say things openly and, some times, a bit roughly but not this time. I apologise if I offended you but could you please explain me what I did wrong?

Comment: I said that due to the comments directed to _lotus. I feel that stack is an open community and we should all treat each other with respect.

Comment: I don't think that this is the right way through (only those who give respect can claim respect), but I accept your advice and understand it as the feeling of the community. I have already apologised to him.